# SSIS Excel File Null Data Microsoft BI

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, business-intelligence

I'm new to SSIS.  When I try to load data from an Excel File and there is another data flow task in the same package, it just fills the table with null data, e.g., dim_Alarm(null,null,null,null).  However, when I try adding a new package and the data flow task is alone in the package, then the data is loaded.

Comment: You may need to clarify your question and add more detail.  So it sounds like one data flow is trying to load data from an Excel file into a table called dim_Alarm.  What is the other data flow doing?  Can you think of any way the second data flow might be interfering with the first data flow?  Are you certain the control flow is really executing the first data flow?  Maybe the control flow is only executing the second data flow?

Comment: in Package i have many data flow task and all dara is filled but just one data flow task is filled by  Null  and when i try to fill the same data from Excel file to the same table in  an empty package data is loaded .

Comment: Look at your comment.  You just restated your original question.  That wasn't the right thing.  I was hoping for _more_ information.  You can get better answers to your questions if you know how to ask a good question to begin with.  And then, when people ask for clarification, you have to know how to add more information to explain it to them.  Remember, we don't understand the problem as well as you do.  You have to explain it to us.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Connection Manager for the Excel Source for the dataflow that is returning null data.  There is probably some difference - maybe a typo error? - between the one that returns null data, and the one that loads the data from the file.

It is unlikely that the presence or absence of the other data flows is causing this problem, unless they are hitting the same Excel file, or they are hitting the same database table dim_Alarm.  It is much more likely that there is some small difference between the data flow that loads nulls and the data flow that works (in the empty package).

You can also add a [Data Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140318.aspx) to the data flow that isn't behaving as you expect.  The Data Viewer goes on one of the arrows between transformations in the data flow.  When you run the package in BIDS, the Data Viewer will show you the data that flows through that point.  If the data is missing, you may be able to see where it got lost.  Is there data coming out of the Excel Source, but after the next transformation there is no more data?  Then that is where the problem is.

Comment: Exactly this is the problem  but i don't know why  it filled by null data

Comment: it doesn't work always i get Null Data i don't know where is the problem :(

Comment: please help me i don't know why table is  filled by Null DATA can you help me please  but when i try on an another empty package it filled :(